# How to check different conditions into if statement based on different scenario

Tags: php

I want to check different conditions into if statement based on different scenario (Will get the `$status` value as `'Y'` or `'N'`). Please check the code below and let me know the issue here.

```
$fstrto = "10"; 
$cstrto = "7";
if($status == 'N')
{
    $cond = "$fstrto <= $cstrto";
}
else
{
    $cond = "$fstrto >= $cstrto";    
}
if($cond)
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

This code is not working as it takes the `"$fstrto <= $cstrto"` as variable.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes. Use intval/doubleval if the input is a string as in `$fstrto = intval($fstrto);`.

```
$fstrto = 10; 
$cstrto = 7;
if($status == 'N')
{
    $cond = $fstrto <= $cstrto;
}
else
{
    $cond = $fstrto >= $cstrto;    
}
if($cond)
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Why it works: `$cond` is being assigned the value of a boolean expression, the values of which can be `true` or `false`. `if($cond)` just checks whether `$cond` is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1):

what is need to do is when using string as a php code use

**eval — Evaluate a string as PHP code**

Use below code work like charm:

```
    $fstrto = "10"; 
    $cstrto = "7";
    if($status == 'N')
    {
    $cond = "$fstrto <= $cstrto";
    }
    else
    {
    $cond = "$fstrto >= $cstrto";    
    }
    if(eval("return $cond;"))
    {
    echo "Success";
    }
```

IMPORTANT:

Use of eval is highly discouraged

NEVER EVER use eval with params by POST/GET without sanitize them

[When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

Comment: If you're going to mention `eval()`, you should also mention why accepting user input into that is a horrible idea - just in case OP wants to use it for something that could be exploited

Answer (score 0):

You `"$fstrto <= $cstrto"` is a string now a compare statement.

```
$fstrto = "10"; 
$cstrto = "7";
if( ($status == 'N' && $fstrto <= $cstrto) || ($status != 'N' && $fstrto >= $cstrto) )
{
  echo "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially turn it into a function that funnels into a `switch` statement like so:

```
function evaluateCondition($status, $a, $b) {
    switch ($status) {
        case 'Y':
            return $a >= $b;
            break;
        case 'N':
            return $a <= $b;
            break;
        default:
            // Error Log. Unknown Status.
    }
}
```

Any future addition can be appended onto the switch statement as necessary, if it gets more convoluted have each case return a separate `function()` to improve readability.

In terms of the current version you could use it like so:

```
$result = evaluateCondition('Y', 5, 6);
var_dump($result); // bool(false)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
$fstrto = "10"; 
$cstrto = "7";
$cond = false;
if($status == 'N')
{
    if($fstrto <= $cstrto){
        $cond = true;
    }

}
else
{
    if($fstrto >= $cstrto){
        $cond = false;
    }
}
if($cond)
{
echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: I think `$cond` should be `true` if `$fstrto >= $cstrto`... Also, I'd define `$cond` with default value of `false` to prevent warnings.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.